# which is the best way for configure log4j2

Tags: log4j2

I am developing one automation testing framework for a web application testing. For this automation framework I want implement logging with log4j2.
In web I found that there is 4 different way to configure the log4j2 configuration 
1) .xml
2) .yml
3) .properties
4) .json

I am confuse which configuration will be better for which purpose. Can anyone explain me for what kind of application/situation which configuration is suitable.
Also I want to know how I can implement log4j2 from start to end (any link)

Answer (score 0):

You're completely free to use any! It's a matter of personal preference.

You can see that they have the same capabilities in the [configuration documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).

A properties file is definitely the simplest, but there's probably more documentation using XML. YAML is much richer, I would start with either properties or XML.